# How to align all the elements to the center in CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I created a Container to center all the elements using **text-align: center;** but for some reason it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

[CODE](https://codepen.io/omrybiton/pen/XWeErPr)

```
Attached is a link to Codepen
```

Thank you :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/omrybiton/pen/XWeErPr

Answer (score 1):

add `margin: 0 auto;` on `container`

```css
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}

.main-pic {
  float: right;
}

.text {
  width: 430px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html dir="rtl">
<div class="container">
     
  <div class="main-pic">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/428x274/cccccc/969696?text=428x274">
  </div>
   
   
  <div class="text">
      <p class="lorem">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda quis
        nemo suscipit itaque. Praesentium suscipit similique, laudantium velit
        qui dolores, eum possimus veritatis id aliquid delectus nesciunt
        voluptatem voluptas! Amet!
      </p>
  </div>
  
      <aside>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x600/cccccc/969696?text=300+x+600" />
      </aside>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks @OmryBiton, don't forget to accept as an answer

Comment: And if I did not set a width of 1200px in the container, how was I supposed to align it to the center?

Answer (score 1):

You can use display flex on the container to center child elements.

```css
.parent {
  background: #dedede;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you .
We are now learning the float :)